# can i pass $_get values as an array in a url?

Tags: php, arrays, get

does it look like

```
?array=hello&array=good&array=bye
```

or should it look like

```
?array[]=hello&array[]=good&array[]=bye
```

and then the get would look like

```
$_GET['array'] = array('hello', 'good', 'bye')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second option is correct:

```
?array[]=hello&array[]=good&array[]=bye
```

(but couldn't you just try and find out?!)

In PHP there is no proper way to get multiple values like

```
?array=hello&array=good&array=bye
```

other than parsing the query string yourself. (afaik)

Comment: @ring0 well yes there are a lot of browsers, but this is a server side issue ;-) (and literally **one** experiment would have revealed the answer!)

Comment: That's correct; the latter would involve multiple overwrites of the same element in the $_GET superglobal.

Answer (score 1):

second method

the first method will treat `$array` as string, and `echo $_GET['array']` output the last one, which is `bye`

you can use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to save some trouble

```
echo http_build_query(array('array'=>array('hello', 'good', 'bye')));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
?array[]=hello&array[]=good&array[]=bye
```

That one.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is correct. Read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

Next time please just give it a go first!